# After switching from one remote to another, __git_ps1 only shows commit hash

Tags: git, git-bash, prompt

I switched my working copy from one remote repo to another by adding the new remote, pushing to the new remote and then removing the old remote and changing new remote name to origin. The only problem is now git bash shows only commit hash at the prompt (running __git_ps1 results in the same thing). `git describe` shows the current commits tag and `git describe --all` shows the correct branch name. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not in detached head state? What give you `git status`?